# What is the name of this generalization of idempotence?

Tags: optimization, haskell, naming, quickcheck

Lots of commonly useful properties of functions have concise names. For example, [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), [commutativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), [transitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_property), etc.

I am making a library for use with [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) that provides shorthand definitions of these properties and others.

The one I have a question about is [idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Unary_operation) of unary functions. A function f is idempotent iif ∀x . f x == f (f x).

There is an interesting generalization of this property for which I am struggling to find a similarly concise name. To avoid biasing peoples name choices by suggesting one, I'll name it P and provide the following definition:

A function f has the P property with respect to g iif ∀x . f x == f (g x). We can see this as a generalization of idempotence by redefining idempotence in terms of P. A function f is idempotent iif it has the P property with respect to itself.

To see that this is a useful property observe that it justifies a rewrite rule that can be used to implement a number of common optimizations. This often but not always arises when g is some sort of canonicalization function. Some examples:

- [`length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:length) is P with respect to [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:map) `f` (for all choices of f)
- Converting to [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) is P with respect to converting to [DNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (and vice versa)
- [Unicode normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) to form NFC is P with respect to normalization to form NFD (and vice versa)
- [`minimum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:minimum) is P with respect to [nub](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:nub)

What would you name this property?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One can say that `map f` is `length`-preserving, or that `length` is invariant under `map f`ing. So how about:

- g is f-preserving.
- f is invariant under (applying) g.

Comment: Also, if f is invariant under a set of operations g, then we can say that is symmetric under g.

Comment: I know that property as `g`-invariant.